# flatbuffers with placeholder references

Tags: java, flatbuffers

I'm using flatbuffers to model an AST-like data structure. Simplified, the schema definition looks like this:

```
namespace schema;

union Statement {
    SimpleStatement;
    FunctionStatement;
}

table SimpleStatement {
   text: string;
}

table FunctionStatement {
    func: Function;
}

table Function {
   text: string;
}

table Component {
    body: [Statement];
}

table Program {
    body: [Component];
}

root_type Program;
```

What I'd like to do is serialize `Component`s into byte arrays and keep them cached. When it comes to serializing the `Program`, I'd deserialize the `Component`s back into their flatbuffers class and add them to the `Program` builder.

That alone would work pretty well, but now the `Function`s come into play. At the time of building a `Component` I don't really have access to the data I need to build its child `Function` objects. To build a `Component` and cache it, I would need to add a placeholder, something I replace with the correct offset to the respective `Function` before including the deserialized `Component` into the `Program` builder. But I have no idea how to do that, if possible at all.

One workaround would be to really save a (more human-like) reference like a string or an int (ID) and also build a map to look up the object later. But that means extra lookups and a slight increase in size.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply need to compose multiple sub-buffers into a final buffer, using the `nested_flatbuffer` attribute is most efficient.

If you still need to change data afterwards though, likely you'd want to be using the "object API", which is currently available quite a few programming languages, but sadly not for Java yet. https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/4769

Failing that, you'd maybe give functions some form of id such that the information that becomes available later can be looked up.

Comment: Thanks, `nested_flatbuffer` is very interesting and certainly useful in many situations. Unfortunately here, I'd need multiple levels of nesting but only have a single place to compose. I went with the "give them some sort of ID" method in such a way, that I actually create the nested tables, but only fill them minimally. Composing the final buffer means some extra work rebuilding the `Component`s, but it solves to many other issues that it is worth it.

Comment: you can nest as deep as you want :)